# When I redirect to another page, the local storage is corrupted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I building ReactJS application.
In local storage, I have init color=red and when I click on a button, I change to color=green and then I do a redirection to PageB. When I am on PageB, I tried to get the color and it returns red. It should return green

```
class PageA extends Component {
    ...
    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem('color', 'green');
        window.location.pathname = '/pageb';
    }

    render() {
        localStorage.setItem('color', 'red');
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <button type='submit'>Go</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function PageB() {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('color'));
    return (
        ...
    );
}
```

Comment: Your `render()` method shouldn't have side effects such as writing into storage. With React you're not truly in control of when it gets called.

Comment: If you only need to set `color` to red once, do it in e.g. `componentDidMount()` or the component's constructor.

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx
In the PageA component, I have just moved the writing into local storage from render() method and put it in constructor and it solves my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use console.log inside PageB, it will throw Unexpected token exception, to solve this issue, you can use below code snippet or visit jsfiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/w7m9f32j/):

```js
class PageA  extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem('color', 'green');
        window.location.pathname = '/pageb';
    }

    render() {
        localStorage.setItem('color', 'red');
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <button type='submit'>Go</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class PageB extends React.Component  {
    componentDidMount() {
     console.log(localStorage.getItem('color'))
    }
    render() {
     return (
     <div><span>hello</span></div>
     );
     }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <PageA name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```